# Makefile with loop and several conditions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a Makefile, here's what I've got till now:

```
all : 
    for var in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do \
        ifneq ("$(wildcard user0$(var).Z)","") \
            //need to add something 
            echo "GNU sort does not exist! Exiting..."; \
        else \
            //some command \
        endif \
    done
```

All the files in the directory are named user01.x, user01.Y, etc.
I want "make all" to have such functionality: First, if such user0$(var).Z) file doesn't exist in the current directory, print error message, but it gives such error:

```
for var in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do \
        ifneq ("","") \
            echo "GNU sort does not exist! Exiting..."; \
        else \
            //some command \
        endif \
    done
/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't know why the wildcard doesn't work. Besides, I would like to add another condition so that (some command) run if .Z file is older than .X and .Y file. (All the files are in the current directory) I know it's trivial if I know all the file names in advance, and I could just hardcode all the file names in Makefile, but how am I suppose to do that in a loop (which already has a condition about whether .Z file exists) ?

Comment: Use shell conditional syntax in the actions.

Comment: You are mixing bash and makefile here, that's why you get the error. Let me propose you something

Comment: Not only does not your question contain C code, even the makefile excerpts you're showing have anything to do with C.

Comment: What do you want Make to do if `user01.Z` exists?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function that does the test and do what you want inside it:

```
list_val=$(shell seq 1 8) 
define test_user
ifeq ("$(wildcard user0$(1).Z)","")
    echo "No file user0$(1).Z";
else
    echo "File user0$(1).Z exists !";
endif
endef
all:
    $(foreach var,$(list_val),$(eval $(call test_user,$(var))))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've described so far can be done like this:

```
Z_FILES := $(patsubst %,user0%.Z, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

all: $(Z_FILES)

$(Z_FILES):
    @echo $@ does not exist
```